# Query set is not empty in django shell but empty in a function

Tags: django

There is the following function in my views.py:

```
def edit_theorem(theorem):
  print(type(theorem))
  print(theorem.id)
  old_list = theorem.included_elements.all()
  print(old_list)
  ...
```

The outputs of these print functions are:

```
<class 'app.models.Theorem'>
65
<QuerySet []>
```

However, when I run `python manage.py shell`, `from app.models import *`, `t=Theorem.objects.get(id=65)`, `print(t.included_elements.all())`, it prints a nonempty queryset.

Why?

My models.py looks like this:

```
class Element(models.Model):
  included_elements = models.ManyToManyField('Element', through='IncludedElements')
  ...

class IncludedElements(models.Model):
  ...

def Theorem(Element):
  ...
```

DB is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure with what you are doing before you call the function **edit_theorm** but I thin that is where the issue is
try

```
def edit_theorem(theorem_id):
  theorem = Theorem.objects.get(id=theorem_id)
  old_list = theorem.included_elements.all()
  print(old_list)

def edit_theorem(request, id):
  //action within the view

  edit_theorem(id)

  //other action within the view
```

Comment: It prints the empty query set.